# Setting Required Managed Metadata Column to hidden with default value?

Tags: content-type, column, managed-metadata, hidden

In a Content Type, I have one managed metadata column (which is required) I want to set it with default value and set it to hidden using powershell. I want to clarify if it possible to hide a required column with default value in Content Type?